# Gradle subproject setup, git submodules

Tags: java, git, gradle, project

I have a gradle (libgdx) project with the following modules

```
- :core
- :a
- :b
```

I'm also including libraries locally as source, to modify them and because they're loosely tied to the project. These projects each have their own structure much like the one for the root project. The final project structure looks like this:

```
 - :core
 - :a
 - :b
 - :libA:core
 - :libA:a
 - :libA:b
 - :libB:core
 - :libB:a
 - :libB:b
```

My question is now, how do I correctly set it up so that i can use `project(':core')` as project dependencies inside of the nested library projects, and still refer to not the `:core` of the root project but to the respective library core modules?
I do not want to modify the dependencies to be like `project(':libA:core')` because that would break the library projects in their standalone form.

Answer (score 1):

You could organize the project like that:

```
/rootDir
  -settings.gradle
  -/core
   -- build.gradle
  -/a
   -- build.gradle  
  -/b
   -- build.gradle  
  -/libA
    -settings.gradle  
    -/core
       -- build.gradle
    -/a
       -- build.gradle  
    -/b
      -- build.gradle       
  -/libB
    -settings.gradle  
    -/core
       -- build.gradle
    -/a
       -- build.gradle  
    -/b
      -- build.gradle
```

Details:

- one `settings.gradle` at the root level, that includes core, a and b projects
- one `settings.gradle` in libA directory, that includes core, a and b projects from libA
- one `settings.gradle` in libB directory, that includes core, a and b projects from libB

This will work if you don't need to reference the "main" code project from the different libA and libB sub-modules.

Comment: Okay, i did that now, but i now my dependencies in the core modules on the library modules don't work. like `:a` depends on `:libA:a`

Comment: ok it was not clear in your question that core modules had dependencies on libA sub-modules... so in this case you will need a single multi-project build, with only one `settings.gradle` file at the root level that includes all sub-modules.  But then you won't be able to do what you asked, because there will be only one project with name `:core` and it will be the one from root level.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible as pointed out by M.Ricciuti due to core modules depending on library modules